# MVC ActionResult trigger Async Task before return View()

Tags: async-await, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm trying to achieve something like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult PostData()
{
    // 1. Need to trigger an async operation for some long processes
    // Trying to trigger SideProcess() async controller

    // Return to view to allow user do other stuff without waiting for above process to complete
    return View("Listing", "Users");
}

public async Task<ActionResult> SideProcess()
{
    ...
}
```

Can I use async task method like above? Because I definitely have to call `PostData()` first on a button click. Otherwise most likely I have to use a different method.

Answer (score 0):

You can, by not `await`-ing the result. This has some drawbacks though. (E.g. what happens if an error occurrs?)

It is better to run the `async` operation in via `Task.Run()` in such cases, since unhandled exceptions will trigger the `TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException` and don't mess with your controller action.

```cs
Task.Run(SideProcess);
```

I tend to use [Hangfire](https://www.hangfire.io/) for such problems in all of my projects and never had an issue. I would recommend and prefer it over the above solution. Comes with very handy oob features for managing BackgroundJobs (including a dashboard, automatic retry mechanisms and many more) while beeing testable too.

Answer (score 0):

Doing that, you won't have any guarantees that your long running process will finish. ASP.NET was purposely not built for that.

But if you have to queue some background work, use [HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.hosting.hostingenvironment.queuebackgroundworkitem).

Beware of the remarks:

> Differs from a normal ThreadPool work item in that ASP.NET can keep track of how many work items registered through this API are currently running, and the ASP.NET runtime will try to delay AppDomain shutdown until these work items have finished executing. This API cannot be called outside of an ASP.NET-managed AppDomain. The provided CancellationToken will be signaled when the application is shutting down.